# How to reshape every nth row's data using pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I need help in reshaping a data in csv file that have over 10000 row by 10 each. For example I have this csv file :

```
Ale Brick
1   ww
2   ee
3   qq
3   xx
5   dd
3   gg
7   hh
8   tt
9   yy
0   uu
1   ii
2   oo
3   pp
4   mm
1   ww
7   zz
1   cc
3   rr
6   tt
9   ll
```

What I am hoping to get is this form where only data in 'Brick' column will be reshaped.

```
[['ww' 'ee' 'qq' 'xx' 'dd']
 ['gg' 'hh' 'tt' 'yy' 'uu']]

[['ii' 'oo' 'pp' 'mm' 'ww']
 ['zz' 'cc' 'rr' 'tt' 'll']]
```

I know how to reshape the data from 0 until 9th row only but did not know how to do it for next 10th row. Here is my script :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    slct = df.head(10)
    result = slct['Brick'].reshape(2,5)

print result
```

This script only print the following result

```
[['ww' 'ee' 'qq' 'xx' 'dd']
 ['gg' 'hh' 'tt' 'yy' 'uu']]
```

I was hoping for it to print the data from 0 to 9th row, 10th to 19th row, 20th row to 29th row and so on...

I have been through the pandas tutorial but did not find any example that looks similar to what I want.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of the modulo operator to "batch" reshape your column. You're on the right track. You just need another iterator to do the modulo operation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'brick': ['xx','yy','xa','bd','ev','bb','oo','pp','qq','bn','nv','bn','rr','qw','bn','cd','fd','bv','nm','ty']})

start = 0  # set start to 0 for slicing
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:  # the modulo operation
        result = df['brick'].iloc[start:i+1].reshape(2,5)
        print result
        start = i + 1  # set start to next index
```

Output:

```
[['xx' 'yy' 'xa' 'bd' 'ev']
 ['bb' 'oo' 'pp' 'qq' 'bn']]
[['nv' 'bn' 'rr' 'qw' 'bn']
 ['cd' 'fd' 'bv' 'nm' 'ty']]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by every 10th row and then reshape the values

```
df.groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(len(df) / 10), 10))['Brick'].apply(lambda x: x.values.reshape(2,5))

0.0    [[ww, ee, qq, xx, dd], [gg, hh, tt, yy, uu]]
1.0    [[ii, oo, pp, mm, ww], [zz, cc, rr, tt, ll]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(`"`test.csv`"`)

data = df['Brick']

k=int(len(data)/10)+1

for x in range(k):

    temp=data[10*x:10*(x+1)]

    print temp.values.reshape(2,5)
```